# Can Nedoma's pathology and other pathologies of larger measure spaces be avoided by changing the definition of sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, cardinals

[Nedoma's pathology](https://www.drmaciver.com/2006/04/journal-of-obscure-results-1-nedomas-pathology/) says that if there is a measurable space $(X,F)$ with $|X|>2^{\aleph_0}$ then the diagonal is not measurable in $X\times X$. This proof relies heavily on the fact that we require sigma algebras to be *countably* additive.

We don't want sigma algebras to be arbitrarily additive because if points are measurable, then everything is measurable.

The main measure space we care about is $\Bbb R$, so we require countable additivity as countability is cardinality lower than the cardinality of the reals.

If we change the definition of sigma algebra to:

> Let $X$ be a set with infinite cardinality $|X|$, a $\sigma$ algebra on $X$ is a subset $\sigma \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ satisfying:
>
> $\emptyset, X\in \sigma$
>
> If $A\in \sigma$ then $X\setminus A\in \sigma$.
>
> If $\{A_\alpha\}$ is a collection of sets with $|\{A_\alpha\}|<|X|$ then $\cup A_\alpha\in \sigma$

do we avoid pathologies like Nedoma's pathology? Does this introduce any new pathologies?

Comment: Martin's Axiom implies that this holds for null sets in the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. I'm not sure if it lifts the additivity for all measurable subsets, though.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sorry I don't quite follow that comment. What holds for null sets?

Comment: That the union of $< \mathfrak{c}$ many null sets is a null set.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure, more importantly the union of $< \mathfrak c$ measurable sets is measurable (assuming the CH).

Comment: Yes, under CH that trivially holds, as $\aleph_0 \le \kappa < \mathfrak{c}$ then implies $\kappa = \aleph_0$, but under MA I'm not sure whether the union of $< \mathfrak{c}$ many (Lebesgue-)measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma hmm, sure. But assuming the CH can we define measure spaces like this to avoid pathologies of higher cardinality measure spaces?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I was referring to models of ZFC where MA also holds. They don’t answer that.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok, sorry for that.

Comment: Just from a notation point of view, using $\sigma$ to denote a $\sigma$-algebra is plain awful, and should be illegal under penalty of flagellation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Lol why? I see this notation used all the time

Comment: It's plain confusing! And what you mean to say, is that you see sinners all the time! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This causes *far* more problems than it solves.  For one thing, the entire theory of (say) Lebesgue measure would fall apart unless you make some major set-theoretic assumptions, since you can't prove in ZFC that the algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets is a Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra by your definition.

Even assuming (say) CH, consider what happens if you try to take a product measure space $[0,1]^I$ of copies of Lebesgue measure where the index set $I$ has cardinality at least $2^{\aleph_0}$.  Then by definition, the "product $\sigma$-algebra" would have to be closed under $2^{\aleph_0}$-sized unions, since $|[0,1]^I|>2^{\aleph_0}$.  But that means that for any $i\in I$ and any $A\subseteq[0,1]$, the set $A\times[0,1]^{I\setminus\{i\}}$ would have to be measurable, since it is the union of the measurable sets $\{a\}\times [0,1]^{I\setminus\{i\}}$ for each $a\in A$.  Since the measure of such a set ought to be the same as the measure of $A$ in $[0,1]$, this means that there would be no reasonable way to define a product measure on the entire "product $\sigma$-algebra", since not every subset of $[0,1]$ is measurable.  Also, for instance, this would mean that the diagonal map $[0,1]\to [0,1]^I$ is not measurable.